# La propiedad 'target' no existe en el tipo 'Object'

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilar, frontend

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Typescript para un proyecto que me piden de cursada, y me en la consola me figura el siguiente error: Property 'target' does not exist on type 'Object'.

```
 function habilitarEdicionItem(event: Object): void {
 const botonClickeado = event.target;
 const divContenedorBoton = botonClickeado.parentElement;
 const itemLista          = divContenedorBoton.parentElement;
 const divTextItem        = itemLista.querySelector('.texto-item');
 divTextItem.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
```

}

Comment: ademas de modificar event:Object  podes mirar esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/q/29168719/8957405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been there intenta esto

```
const btn: HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementById("my-btn");

function getDad<T extends HTMLElement> (el: T) {return el.parentElement;}

function handler (this:HTMLButtonElement, evt: MouseEvent) {
 const abuelo: HTMLDivElement = getDad (getDad (this));
}

btn.addEventListener("click", handler);
```

Comment: Lo intento dentro de la función, o como una función nueva?